# Is it proper grammar to say "on today" and "on tomorrow?"

Tags: grammar

In my town, people with PhD's in education use the terms, "on today" and "on tomorrow." I have never heard this usage before. Every time I hear them say it, I wonder if it is correct to use the word "on" in this way. The word "on" is commonly used with the days of the week-"on Monday," "on Saturday." It seems that using the word "on" is not correct terminology and it should be only "tomorrow," "Monday," etc. Please explain...

Comment: I visited a webpage about this a few days ago by chance while killing time in the office. https://painintheenglish.com/case/3919/  Some comments are hilarious. The OP says; "After moving from Chicago down to northeastern Georgia, I have noticed an extremely vexing trend among many of the native Southerners. The phrase “on tomorrow,” i.e."

Comment: By the way, I just realized that the webpage is editing texts for a price. So if my above comment is considered advertising, I (or any mods) can immediately delete.

Comment: The usage is not idiomatic US English, through most of the US.  It's hard to claim that it's not syntactically valid, however.

Comment: It depends on the rest of the sentence and possibly on the wider context. The following are fine: "You may submit your report on Monday."; "Was the event cancelled? No, it is still on today." However, the following would not be considered standard English (in BrE, at least): "You may submit your report *on today."

Comment: What is the  general region of the world that this usage might be heard? People in NYC say *on line* (as in to stand on line to buy a movie ticket)  but I think that's the only place in the USA where that phrase is used, the more widespread phrase being *in line*.

Comment: Also if you could provide examples of the phrase in a complete sentence, that would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is probably a case of **dialect**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialect)'s first sense is:

> (1) a regional variety of language distinguished by features of vocabulary, grammar, and pronunciation from other regional varieties and constituting together with them a single language.

WIthin the context of this dialect, the formation "on today" and "on yesterday" would be considered correct by those speakers, or they wouldn't be saying it that way. However (and I cannot back this up with a citation), in general, most English speakers in the US would not use "on" before "today" or "tomorrow."

There are also interesting points about the etymology of "today" and "tomorrow" (think of the archaic usage "on the morrow") that are beyond the scope of what you're asking.